# Cant install psych package

Tags: r, install.packages, psych

I am new to R-studio and I am trying to install the `psych` package but I get the following error:

```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘psych’ in loadNamespace(j
> <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
> is no package called ‘mnormt’
```

So then I tried to install the `mnormt` package and I get the following message:

```
> package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in
> install.packages :   cannot remove prior installation of package
> ‘mnormt’ Warning in install.packages :   restored ‘mnormt’
```

But when I then try to install the `psych` package it keeps saying that the `mnormt` package was not installed.

Comment: Try restarting your R and installing it again before loading any other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be first to deinstall the defect package and afterwards run a fresh install:

```
remove.packages("mnormt")
```

Reinstall mnormt with:

```
install.packages("mnormt")
```

Then install psych package:

```
install.packages("psych")
```

Could have happened some files were transferred incompletely/broken after your first installation of mnormt.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens as one of the packages (that the package you are trying to install depends upon) is not installing properly.

First, try to

```
install.packages("mnormt")
```

Then try to install the psych package again as usual

```
install.packages("psych")
```