# Cannot install psych package on R 3.6.0 on CentOS 7.8.2003

Tags: r

I am using R 3.6.0 on CentOS 7.8.2003.

When I enter

```
install.packages("psych")
```

I get the following results

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/psych_1.9.12.31.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1724122 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for package ‘psych’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/psych’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpF7bh0e/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("psych") :
  installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I try

```
install.packages("mnormt")
```

I get

```
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘mnormt’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
```

I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845922/cant-install-any-r-packages-on-linux-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471381/cant-install-psych-package) but neither worked.  Is it not possible to install the psych package on R 3.6.0?

Comment: The `mnormt` is a dependency for `psych` and the latest version requires R 4.0. You can manually [install an older version of that package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) and then try to install `psych` after that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct.  I downloaded mnormt_1.5-7.tar.gz and ran "sudo R CMD INSTALL mnormt_1.5-7.tar.gz".  That fixed the problem.  Thanks very much,